# what breaker amp rating, do I need for a 230 volt 1PH motor 10.9 amp, fed by double pole breaker 115 v each leg?

Tags: irrigation, lawn

This is for a lawn irrigation sprinkler system. I am changing out to a new pump and need to verify the amp rating of the double pole breaker I need to use to deliver 115 volts to each leg of the motor. The FLA of the motor is 10.9 amps. will a 20 amp be too light and be tripping and or should I use a 30 amp rated CB?

Answer (score 1):

Table 430.52(C)(1) says 250% for inverse time circuit breaker, using Table 430.248 at 8.0A for 1 hp resulting in 20A inverse time breaker. If unable to start the motor without tripping then 430.52(C)(1)(b)(3) allows increasing the breaker up to 400%, so 30A could be allowed.

Minimum wire size needs to be 125% of nameplate applied to Table 310.16, #14 will be minimum size, larger wire would be needed for long distances.

Proper overload protection must also be provided.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the motor nameplate and instructions. Really.

Right on there it will state a minimum circuit ampacity and a maximum circuit breaker.  You need to pick a breaker size in that range.   I.e. it might be min 12.8A max 25A.   So a 15A breaker will suffice.  If you're that worried about it nuisance tripping, use the max.

A 30A is not legal unless it says so.  And yes, 25A is a standard size.  Actually it's a correct size for 4500W water heaters.

If the labeling is silent, then you go over to NEC Article 430, but it's unlikely for UL to approve a motor without that data.

Generally when a motor has a wide gap between minimum ampacity and maximum breaker, it is because the motor has overload protection on the motor, thus the breaker size does not need to be a precise match.

Answer (score -1):

15 amps double pole breaker is the size you want.

Larger breakers might cause more damage to the pump if there is a problem.

15 amp breaker must use 14 gauge wire at the minimum, but larger gauge wire is allowed and recommended for large distances(~plus 100 feet) to reduce voltage drop.